# Unit Testing .net Web Api. Setting Query String values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest

The first line of my ApiController HttpGet action is this

```
var returnOnlyDefault = (Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
    .Any(kv => ((kv.Key.ToLower() == "defaultview") && (kv.Value.ToLower() == "true"))));
```

This looks for a query string value of "defaultview".  The code 'works', but i'm having trouble unit testing it.

In my unit test i am doing the following

```
var controller = new Controllers.ViewsController { Request = new HttpRequestMessage() };
controller.Request.Properties.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("defaultview", "true"));
```

the request uri is null of course. The test is failing as it doesn't pick up the query string value.

Answer (score 15):

You should set the request Uri:

```
controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:51083/?param1=someValue&param2=anotherValue");
```

Now the get querystring params in your ApiController works as expected:

```
var queryStringParams = Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().ToList();
var param1 = queryStringParams.FirstOrDefault(kv => kv.Key.Equals("param1")).Value;
```

param1 is now 'someValue' and the unit test runs.